# $\log f \sim \log g$ does not imply $f \sim g$, but what can we say?

Tags: soft-question, asymptotics

So, $f(x) \sim g(x)$ easily implies $\log f(x) \sim \log g(x)$, (as $x \to a$, say, and assuming non-stupid cases that don't make sense like $f(x)<-3$, etc.):

$$\frac{\log f}{\log g} = \frac{\log \left( \frac{f}{g} \cdot g \right)}{\log g} = \frac{\log \frac{f}{g}}{\log g} + 1 \sim 0 + 1 = 1.$$

But the converse is false.  For example, $f(x)=xe^x$ and $g(x)=e^x$ and $a = \infty$.

**Question:**  What useful things, if any?, can fill in the blank $$\log f(x) \sim \log g(x) \implies \underline{\hspace{13mm}}?$$

I haven't seen much in the related questions, but feel free to link any that you think are useful.

Comment: What is $\sim$ ?

Comment: In your example, it looks like $f,g$ are *not* asymptotic as $x \to \infty,$ in the sense that $f/g=x$ doesn't approach $1$ (or even a positive finite constant).

Comment: @coffeemath Yes.  That's the point.  But $f$ and $g$ do have some relationship.  For example, $f(x)=e^{e^x}$ and $g(x)=e^x$ would not have $\log f  \sim \log g$.

Comment: @Adayah $f \sim g$ (with respect to some point $a \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm \infty\}$) is the standard asymptotic notation: $$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} =1.$$

Comment: No more than $\frac{\log{f(x)}}{\log{g(x)}}=\frac{\log{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}g(x)}}{\log{g(x)}}=1+\frac{\log{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}}{\log{g(x)}} \sim 1$ probably

Comment: @rtybase Yeah, I figured.  But asked just to make sure..

Comment: Dzooks-- Also $f=e^{e^x}, g=e^x$ aren't asymptotic at $\infty.$ Do you have any specific case where $f,g$ *are* asymptotic but their logs are not?

Comment: @coffeemath Read the question carefully. $f \sim g \implies \log f \sim \log g$ but not conversely.

Comment: DZooks Now I see I was looking at it "backwards."

Answer (score 1):

Let $D=\text{dom}(f)\cap \text{dom}(g).$  Assume that $a\in\overline {D\setminus \{a\}}.$    For $r>0$ let$ E(r)=(D\cap (r+a,r+a))\setminus \{a\}.$ Assume $r_1>0$ and that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are positive for all $x\in E(r_1) .$ Assume  that $\lim_{x\to a}(\log f(x))/\log g(x)=1$ as $x\to a$ thru members of $E(r_1).$ Then $$f(x)=g(x)\cdot g(x)^{d(x)}$$ for $x\in E(r_1)$, where $4d(x)\to 0$ as $x\to a$ through members of $E(r_1).$

Now if for some $r_2\in (0,r_1]$ we have  $0< \inf \{f(x):x\in E(r_2)\}\leq \sup \{f(x):x\in E(r_2)\}<\infty$ then $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)/g(x) =1 .$... Even if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ does not exist.... We can also interchange $f$ with $g$ in this.  Or interchange $f$ with $1/f$ and interchange $g$ with $1/g.$

But if $f$ or $1/f$ or $g$ or $1/g$  is not bounded on any $E(r)$ then there is nothing  we can say about $f(x)/g(x)$ as $x\to a.$